# Merge two arrays with the same keys and different length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve the problem but couldn't figure out how to do it. 
I have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [
     {Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1}, {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12}, 
     {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3}, {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5}
];

var arr2 = [
     {Week: "WK1", ClosedTickets: 4}, {Week: "WK6", ClosedTickets: 40},
     {Week: "WK3", ClosedTickets: 33}, {Week: "WK2", ClosedTickets: 2}
 ];
```

The expected output would be and the week should be in order as well.

```
var output = [
     {Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1, ClosedTickets: 4}, 
     {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3, ClosedTickets: 2},
     {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12, ClosedTickets: 33},
     {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5, ClosedTickets: 0},
     {Week: "WK6", CreatedTickets: 0, ClosedTickets: 33}
];
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.

Jamie

Comment: At least, lie to us `:)` you did something!

Comment: It is simple but i couldn't figure out the logic. Please help me to solve it. I  would like to see the solution. Thanks.

Comment: We'd really like to see your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I did try different ways but couldn't find the solution that's why I don't want to post it.

Comment: People, please remember not everyone is a JS expert when asking a question on SO.  For beginners solving a problem like this can be mind boggling.  Not even knowing where to start.  So please, at least give this newcomer some ideas / where to look etc.  And in some respects the problem is not as easy as some make out.  The `week should be in order as well` could have a slight gotcha that's not trivial to sort out.

Comment: @Jamie, post out the codes you already tried. Perhaps you already fnished 90% of the trip.

Comment: If you guys can provide me hints of how to approach this problem, I would be appreciated.

Comment: It's OK if your solution doesn't work. That's why you've asked the question ... [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom sorting function is something you could start from.

Comment: I know the sort method in an array but I am stuck how to set ClosedTickets to 0 when the week is not found in another array.

Answer (score 0):

You can map (using `reduce`) the initial arrays to get a faster access to their keys, then execute a loop using `forEach` to build the desired result.

Now, execute a `sort` over result array using the `Week` value (Just the numbers).

```js
var arr1 = [{Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1}, {Week: "WK20", CreatedTickets: 7}, {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12}, {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3}, {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5}],
    arr2 = [{Week: "WK1", ClosedTickets: 4}, {Week: "WK6", ClosedTickets: 40},{Week: "WK3", ClosedTickets: 33}, {Week: "WK2", ClosedTickets: 2}],
    // Convert to something like this:
    //  {
    //    "WK1": {
    //      "Week": "WK1",
    //      "CreatedTickets": 1
    //    },
    //    "WK20": {
    //      "Week": "WK20",
    //      "CreatedTickets": 7
    //    },
    //  }
    //
    // This is to speed up the access and comparisons.
    //
    map1 = arr1.reduce((a, o) => ({...a, ...{[o.Week]: o}}), {}),
    map2 = arr2.reduce((a, o) => ({...a, ...{[o.Week]: o}}), {});
 
 // Now let's loop the keys of the previously mapped 'map1'.
 Object.keys(map1).forEach(k => {
  if (map2[k]) {
    // This is to avoid the values ("WK1", "WK2", and so on.) 
    // because map1 already has that value.
    delete map2[k].Week; 
    
    // Will generate something like this:
    // { 
    //   WK1: {
    //     "Week": "WK1",
    //     "CreatedTickets": 1,
    //     "ClosedTickets": 4
    //   }
    // }
    map1[k] = { ...map1[k], ...map2[k] };        
  } else {
    // Will generate something like this:
    // { 
    //   WK1: {
    //     "Week": "WK1",
    //     "CreatedTickets": 7,
    //     "ClosedTickets": 0 // To initialize qith zero because is an object that doesn't exists in map2
    //   }
    // }
    map1[k] = { ...map1[k], ...{CreatedTickets: map1[k].CreatedTickets, ClosedTickets: 0} };    
  }
 });
 
 // Now the same forEach for the map2 to complete with the missing objects (weeks) in map1
 Object.keys(map2).forEach(k => {
  if (!map1[k]) {
    map1[k] = { ...map1[k], ...{Week: map2[k].Week, CreatedTickets: 0, ClosedTickets: map2[k].ClosedTickets} };    
  }
 });
 
 // Justa a sort
 var sorted = Object.values(map1).sort((a,b) => a.Week.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '') - b.Week.replace(/[a-z]/gi, ''));
 console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Erie,

Thanks for your help. The output is missing {Week: "WK6"} in the last object.

Comment: nice one.. :)   Your shows ESNext features I mentioned, so it's good having this answer too.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works! 
Ele, your code is really complicated. I don't fully understand. Would you tell me what is ..a used for?

Comment: @Jamie use the approach of `Keith` I think it's a better solution **(simpler to understand)** because you need to understand `Spread syntax` first.

Comment: @Jamie see the updated answer with some comments, hope you understand! `:)`

Comment: Thanks guys. 
@Keith - your approach is simpler and easier to understand. I'm really appreciated for both of your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some shortcuts you could use if using ESNext features, but since you have been using `var` and not `let` / `const`, I'm assuming ES5 only.

So below is a simple solution.

```js
var arr1 = [
     {Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1}, 
     {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12}, 
     {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3},
     {Week: "WK20", CreatedTickets: 7},
     {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5}
];

var arr2 = [
     {Week: "WK1", ClosedTickets: 4}, 
     {Week: "WK6", ClosedTickets: 40},
     {Week: "WK3", ClosedTickets: 33},
     {Week: "WK2", ClosedTickets: 2}
];

//first lets make a copy of arr1
var output = arr1.slice();

//now loop arr2, and see if exists in ouput or not
arr2.forEach(function (item) {
  //lets find in arr1
  var f = output.find(function(i) { return item.Week === i.Week; });
  if (f) {
    //ok found lets update
    f.ClosedTickets = item.ClosedTickets;
  } else {
    //not found lets add
    output.push(item);
  }
});

//ok if we want 0, for OpenTickets and ClosedTickets if none found
output.forEach(function (item) {
  item.ClosedTickets = item.ClosedTickets | 0;
  item.CreatedTickets = item.CreatedTickets | 0;
});

//finally lets's sort
//one gotcha, sorting by WK1,WK2,WK10 etc in string sort would give
//WK1, WK10, WK2.. so we will use regex to extract just the wk part
//convert to integer and then sort

var regexnum = /\d+/;

function numWk(s) {
  return parseInt(regexnum.exec(s.Week)[0], 10);
}

output.sort(function (a,b) { return numWk(a) - numWk(b); });

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Your solution is simple and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option,

Two loops for getting exact output

1. First loop to create Object in below format

   {
           "WK1": { 
               "CreatedTickets": 1,
               "ClosedTickets": 4
           },
           "WK2": {
               "CreatedTickets": 3,
               "ClosedTickets": 2
           },
           "WK3": {
               "CreatedTickets": 12,
               "ClosedTickets": 33
           },
           "WK5": {
               "CreatedTickets": 5,
               "ClosedTickets": 0
           },
           "WK6": {
               "CreatedTickets": 0,
               "ClosedTickets": 33
           }
       }
2. Second loop for converting temp Object mentioned above to output array

   [
         {Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1, ClosedTickets: 4},
         {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3, ClosedTickets: 2},
         {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12, ClosedTickets: 33},
         {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5, ClosedTickets: 0},
         {Week: "WK6", CreatedTickets: 0, ClosedTickets: 33}
   ];

**JS**

```js
var output =[];//output array
var temp = {};//temp object

var arr1 = [
     {Week: "WK1", CreatedTickets: 1}, {Week: "WK3", CreatedTickets: 12}, 
     {Week: "WK2", CreatedTickets: 3}, {Week: "WK5", CreatedTickets: 5}
];

var arr2 = [
     {Week: "WK1", ClosedTickets: 4}, {Week: "WK6", ClosedTickets: 40},
     {Week: "WK3", ClosedTickets: 33}, {Week: "WK2", ClosedTickets: 2}
 ];

var concatArr = arr1.concat(arr2)



for(var o of concatArr){
  if(Object.keys(temp).indexOf(o.Week)==-1){
   temp[o.Week] ={}
   o.ClosedTickets?temp[o.Week].ClosedTickets = o.ClosedTickets:temp[o.Week].ClosedTickets = 0
   o.CreatedTickets?temp[o.Week].CreatedTickets = o.CreatedTickets:temp[o.Week].CreatedTickets = 0
  }else{
   o.ClosedTickets?temp[o.Week].ClosedTickets = temp[o.Week].ClosedTickets + o.ClosedTickets:temp[o.Week].ClosedTickets
   o.CreatedTickets?temp[o.Week].CreatedTickets = temp[o.Week].CreatedTickets + o.CreatedTickets:temp[o.Week].CreatedTickets
 }
}

for( var key of Object.keys(temp)){
  output.push({
    Week:key,
    CreatedTickets:temp[key].CreatedTickets,
    ClosedTickets:temp[key].ClosedTickets
  })
}

console.log(output)
```

Code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RMNVvQ?editors=1010